# Não consigo executar uma query de pesquisa com PHP e SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

boa noite

Sou nova em php, e estou tenho problemas na hora de fazer o campo de pesquisa funcionar. Estou fazendo um sistema que possui uma página de tutoriais, que tem os cards com as informações dos tutoriais e um campo de pesquisa. Fiz um laço para exibir as informações e seus respectivos cards e uma consulta, e deu tudo certo. Entretanto, quando adiciono a query de pesquisa, não acontece absolutamente nada - coloquei para retornar o nome do tutorial numa div, apenas para testar. Não sei o que está acontecendo, se é algum erro lógico ou de sintaxe. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obs: mudei a posição do código de pesquisa diversas vezes, essa minha última tentativa foi a mais desesperadora ksks

```
    <?php
require_once "config.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Tutoriais</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estiloTutoriais2.css"/> 

</head>

<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="tutoriais.php">Tutoriais</a>
        <a href="forum.php">Forum</a>
        <a href="contato.php">Contato</a>
    </div>

<ul id="listaH"> 
 <li> <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; OPUS</span></li>
</ul>

<section>

 <div class="images">
    <img src="images/tutoriais.png" width="800px" height="500px">
 </div>

 <h1 id="titulo_pag"> Tutoriais </h1> <br> 



  <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
    $sql_pesq = "SELECT * FROM tutoriais WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%' ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql_pesq);

    while($rows_t = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

        ?>
          <div>  <?php echo "Nome do tutorial: ".$rows_t['nome']."<br>";  ?> </div>
        <?php
    }
    mysqli_close($link); 
}

?>

<input type="text" name="pesquisar" placeholder="Pesquisar Tutorial"> 
  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">


<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from tutoriais";
$result = $link -> query($sql) or die ($link -> error );
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
?>
 <div class="container">
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                <img src="images/<?php echo $row["imagem"];?>">
                <h3><?php echo $row["nome"];?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p> <b> <?php echo $row["titulo"];?> </b> </p>
                    <p><?php echo $row["descricao"];?> </p>
                        <a href="<?php echo $row["link"];?>" target="_blank">Mais</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
     <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php 
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else{
    echo "Não foram encontrados registros que correspondam a query.";
} 

mysqli_close($link);

?>



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>

</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Você tentou executar a query de consulta direto no banco de dados para ver se é retornado algum dado ?

Comment: Acabei de executar, e tá funcionando normalmente (no banco). Quando eu ainda não tinha criado a outra query pra exibir os cards, tinha utilizado o mesmo código e estava funcionando

Comment: tente dar um var_dump($resultado) para verificar se os dados estão chegando.

Comment: Assim a primeira vista, sem saber o que tem no .js, o que vejo em falta é um tag `<form>` à volta dos input / submit.

Comment: Caso o problema seja a condição do if não estar sendo atendida, eu sugiro que você teste se o campo pesquisar não esta vazio, para então fazer a pesquisa.

Comment: Gente, era isso mesmo. Estava me esquecendo do form, no qual insiro o método post. Meu Deus, não sei como não reparei antes. Enfim, muito obrigada!!